# Criação de JSON com numeral

Tags: javascript, json

Gostaria de criar um JSON assim (essa é apenas uma parte), crio sempre o objeto com o valor, porém não consigo fazer dessa forma utilizando o `200` como objeto:

```
path.get.response = new Object()
path.get.response.200 = new Object()

  "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Operação realizada com sucesso!",
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
```

....

Comment: `path.get.response.["200"] = new Object()`

Comment: @Isac interessante, dessa forma você converte 200 para string né? Só que depois para acessar esse objeto é só dessa forma também né? `path.get.response.["200"]`

Comment: Sim, no entanto enganei me e coloquei um `.` a mais. É apenas `path.get.response["200"]`

Comment: não funcionou dessa forma amigos...

Answer (score 0):

É realmente necessário nomear o objeto como 200? Acredito que objetos não podem iniciar com **número**, **hífen** ou **carácter especial**. Talvez o ideal seria você chama-lo de `status200` ou `S200`, enfim depende da sua criatividade.

> Um nome de propriedade de um objeto pode ser qualquer string
>   JavaScript válida, ou qualquer coisa que possa ser convertida em uma
>   string, incluindo uma string vazia. No entanto, qualquer nome e
>   propriedade que **não é um identificador JavaScript válido** (por exemplo,
>   **um nome de propriedade que tem um espaço ou um hífen, ou que começa
>   com um número**) só pode ser acessado(a) usando-se a notação de
>   colchetes [...]

Você pode conferir mais nesse artigo - [Trabalhando com Objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabalhando_com_Objetos)

Comment: De acordo com o exemplo do json o nome do objeto deveria ser 200, pois é a definição do json, mas se não tem como fazer isso com objeto e valor, terei que achar outra alternativa.

Comment: A API te retorna o objeto assim ou esse JSON está local?

Comment: Eu estou gerando esse json, em cima de padroes existentes, estou fazendo um gerador, onde eu digito as informações e o gerador gera o json, mas acho que vou gerar com outro nome no lugar do 200 e ao gerar o arquivo eu renomeio para 200.

Comment: Entendi, tem a maneira que o @Isaac mostrou também `path.get.response.["200"]`, pelo que entendi dessa forma você converte o 200 para string, seria uma forma de contornar esse problema